# Submit new paste to Paste.ee API using PHP Curl doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to submit a new paste to Paste.ee API using Curl, but the response is always Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Here's the guideline of Paste.ee API: https://paste.ee/wiki/API:Basics

Here's how my simple code looks like:

```html
<?php 
$key = '56b3f127d65445c0cf6ff05f62ffba53';
$format = 'JSON';
$description = 'just for testing';
$paste = 'Just a simple test';

  if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://paste.ee/api");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:")); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("key" => $key, "format" => $format, "description" => $description, "paste" => $paste)); 
   
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $response;

  } else {
   error_log("You need cURL to use this api!");
  }
?>
```

I've double-checked, my key is right.
I'm new to Curl, so any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You get that response from the Paste.ee API? Any of [these](https://paste.ee/wiki/API:Errors) error codes? What makes you think it is an issue with your usage of curl?

Comment: Hi Jmills, the error looks like this: [link](http://prnt.sc/dqhhb9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because "format" is case sensitive in which it must small letters

You your format is capitalised which is it should be small letters

```
"format": "json"
```

look

```
$key = '56b3f127d65445c0cf6ff05f62ffba53';
$format = 'JSON';
$description = 'just for testing';
$paste = 'Just a simple test';
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://paste.ee/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'key' => $key,
    'format' => $format,
    'description' => 'just for testing',
    'paste' => $paste,
    'format' => 'json'
    ));
```

**CAPITALISED WHICH RETURNS ERROR** 
[image]

**small letters which returns the correct json data** 
[image]

Comment: Gee. Thanks a lot mate, I din't notice that.